# Bokeh callback function with image editing not working with pyscript

Tags: python-imaging-library, bokeh, pyscript

I am using pyscript to take an image and process it. I am using a bokeh widget to make changes to the image through callback function. The callback function works but stops when I use Pillow to convert the image to greyscale.

Imports:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import js
from js import document, console, Uint8Array, window, File, Bokeh, JSON, localStorage
from pyodide import create_proxy
import asyncio
import io
import json  

from bokeh import __version__
from bokeh.document import Document
from bokeh.embed.util import OutputDocumentFor, standalone_docs_json_and_render_items
from bokeh.models import Slider, Div
from bokeh.layouts import Row
from bokeh.protocol.messages.patch_doc import process_document_events
```

```
def callback(attr, old, new):
    div.text = f'Symbol is: {new}'
    first_item = localStorage.getItem('key')
    print(first_item)
    my_image = imageToBinary(first_item)
    print(my_image)
    rs_img = convertBintoRS(my_image,8)
    rs_img = encodeRS(rs_img, 5, 6)
    rs_img = seperate_img(rs_img,5+6,5)
    rs_img = RStoBinary(rs_img,8)
    rs_img = binaryToImage(rs_img)
    display_image(rs_img,"reed_s")

p.on_change('value', callback)

row = Row(children=[p, div])
```

```
def imageToBinary(img):
    print('enter imageToBinary')
    img = img.convert('L')
    print('convert to greyscale')
    print(img)
    img = np.array(img)
    print('convert numpy')
    x,y = np.shape(img)
    print(x,y)
    for i in range(0,x):
        for j in range(0,y):
            if img[i][j] < 255/2:
                img[i][j] = 0
            else:
                img[i][j] = 1
    print('success')
    return img
```

I am also including this which is some code that is relevant to the bokeh widget.

```
def doc_json(model, target):
    with OutputDocumentFor([model]) as doc:
        doc.title = ""
        docs_json, _ = standalone_docs_json_and_render_items(
            [model], suppress_callback_warning=False
        )

    doc_json = list(docs_json.values())[0]
    root_id = doc_json['roots']['root_ids'][0]

    return doc, json.dumps(dict(
        target_id = target,
        root_id   = root_id,
        doc       = doc_json,
        version   = __version__,
    ))

def _link_docs(pydoc, jsdoc):
    def jssync(event):
        if getattr(event, 'setter_id', None) is not None:
            return
        events = [event]
        json_patch = jsdoc.create_json_patch_string(pyodide.ffi.to_js(events))
        pydoc.apply_json_patch(json.loads(json_patch))

    jsdoc.on_change(pyodide.ffi.create_proxy(jssync), pyodide.ffi.to_js(False))

    def pysync(event):
        json_patch, buffers = process_document_events([event], use_buffers=True)
        buffer_map = {}
        for (ref, buffer) in buffers:
            buffer_map[ref['id']] = buffer
        jsdoc.apply_json_patch(JSON.parse(json_patch), pyodide.ffi.to_js(buffer_map), setter_id='js')

    pydoc.on_change(pysync)

async def show(plot, target):
    pydoc, model_json = doc_json(plot, target)
    views = await Bokeh.embed.embed_item(JSON.parse(model_json))
    jsdoc = views[0].model.document
    _link_docs(pydoc, jsdoc)

asyncio.ensure_future(show(row, 'myplot'))
```

1. The callback function stops within imageToBinary at the print('enter imageToBinary')
2. I know the function works outside the callback function.
3. I have printed the item going into localStorage and out of it to check it is the same but type() wouldn't work and gave an error.

Comment: Do you have any error message? Did you check the browser console for error messages, to check if something failed in JS?

Comment: @mosc9575 thankyou. that gave me the debugging information i need. The object had been turned into a string, which PIL can't work with. Cheers